# The roots of a polynomial in one complex variable lie in the upper-half plane [CSIR 2015]

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p$ be a polynomial in 1-complex variable.Suppose all zeroes of $p$ are in the upper half plane $H=\{z \in \mathbb{C} :Im(z)> 0 \}$.

Then which of the following are true?

1. $Im  \frac {p'(z)}{ p(z)} \gt 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $Re \ i\frac {p'(z)}{ p(z)} \lt 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$.
3. $Im  \frac {p'(z)}{ p(z)} \gt 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, with $Im \ z\lt0$.
4. $Im  \frac {p'(z)}{ p(z)} \gt 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, with $Im \ z\gt0$.

I am not able to approach this question.1 thing i can observe is that in options 1,2 and 3 $p(z)$ will be non-zero hence well defined but in option 4 if z happens to be a root,it is not well defined.

Comment: Approach it first by example. Choose a polynomial $p(z)$ which satisfies the assumptions, and see which of 1.,2.,3.,4., is true.

Comment: If we define the "logarithmic derivative" of $f$ by $L(f)=f'/f$ then $L(fg)=L(f)+L(g)$. Your polynomial is a product of linear factors...

Comment: If p(z)=(z-a) where  a€C ,Im(a)>0; it is easy to check these options. Can the result be generalized then?